# Hiding exception handling logic of a web service with java bindings from scala clients

Tags: scala

Im using java bindings for a web service (virtualbox) and i would like to hide the boilerplate what is needed for error handling of the web service. The usage of the java bindings looks like this:

```
val mgr = VirtualBoxManager.createInstance(null)
mgr.connect("http://localhost:18083", null, null)

val vBox: IVirtualBox = mgr.getVBox()
```

And then i mainly use the variable xBov to do stuff on the web service. When the connection times out it throws an exception and i would like to hide this exception handling from the client code and reconnect sliently. In java I would write a proxy Object which hides the real object in question and just delegates the work to that and do the error handling behind the scenes. To do this i have to implement all the methods listed in IVirtualBox interface which i dont want in this case because there are plenty of them...

I'm wondering if there is a simpler or more elegant way to do this in Scala?